# Swapping First Name with Last Name and Vice Versa in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a dataset with a name column which has last name and first name. I need to swap them to have first name and last name. Here's my dataset:

```
df=data.frame(Id=c("10","50"), Name=c("NAGAR MAYANK","PETER MARK"), Street= c("Newark Ave","Grant Ave"),Country=c("NJ","TX"))
```

I have tried the below code to work:

```
sub("(\\w+),\\s(\\w+)","\\2\\1", dummy$Name)
```

However, this gives me the name as it is, i.e., "NAGAR MAYANK" and "PETER MARK".

I need the output as below:

```
| Id | Name          | Street     | State |
|----|---------------|------------|-------|
| 10 | MAYANK NAGAR  | Newark Ave | NJ    |
| 50 | MARK PETER    | Grant Ave  | TX    |
```

Comment: You have a `,` in your regex after the first word, which is causing the search to fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct, it just includes a comma which isn't present in the strings so the pattern isn't detected and no matching/replacement is done. (As noted by @Mosquite)

```
df$Name <- sub('(\\w) (\\w)', '\\2 \\1', df$Name)

df
#   Id         Name     Street Country
# 1 10 MAYANK NAGAR Newark Ave      NJ
# 2 50   MARK PETER  Grant Ave      TX
```

Comment: Can you double check the regex? For me `sub('(\\w+) (\\w+)', '\\2 \\1', df$Name)` worked.

Answer (score 5):

For this, you can use `word()` from `stringr` library:

```
df$Name <- with(df, paste(word(Name, 2), word(Name, 1)))

  Id         Name     Street Country
1 10 MAYANK NAGAR Newark Ave      NJ
2 50   MARK PETER  Grant Ave      TX
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be `cSplit`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
df.tmp <- cSplit(df, "Name", " ")
df$Name <- paste(df.tmp$Name_2, df.tmp$Name_1, sep =" ")

> df
  Id         Name     Street Country
1 10 MAYANK NAGAR Newark Ave      NJ
2 50   MARK PETER  Grant Ave      TX
```